# Is there a way to get the name of the local function that is being run in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to get the name of the local function that is being run in Matlab?

Note: `mfilename` returns the name of the .m file, not the name of the local function.

Comment: I wonder why you need this?

Comment: "that is being run" when? During execution? Debugging? Last run function?

Comment: @Mendo: This is being run during execution and also for debugging purpose..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbstack` returns a struct with the full function call stack. To get the information for the top level function, use:

```
S=dbstack
fname=S(1).name
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a page on the [Matlab Central website](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/172176) which appears to answer your question.  Here is the code they recommend using:

```
[ST,I] = dbstack;
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = ST.name;
```

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION` should contain the name of the local function which is executing.

Comment: ... except that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not a valid MATLAB identifier, and `ST` is an array. What the OP needs is `PRETTY_FUNCTION = ST(1).name`.

Comment: @Edric: `ST.name` is a comma separated list, `x=ST.name` assigns the first element. One should use indexing here to make the human code readable, but it is not necessary.

Comment: I agree it's not necessary, but it's surely preferable.